# Find the most frequent word over the latest K words

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

I was trying to solve this problem:

> The idea is quite simple, your program will keep reading from a stream where new words are continuously being fed to your program, but due to limited storage, your program can only remember the latest K words. So, when (K+1)th word arrives, your program forgets the 1st word, when (k+2)th word arrives, your program forgets the 2nd word, and so on.

We want you to find the most frequent word over the latest `K` words each time a new word arrives. I tried solving the problem using map (as hash table) deque (to maintain the input stream). Below is my code which I have tried but for some cases it is not giving the desired result.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define ps pair<string,int>
map<string,int>dir;
int lookup( string name)
{

    map<string,int>::iterator it;
    dir[name]+=1;
    it=dir.find(name);
    return it->second;
}
void update(string name)
{
    map<string,int>::iterator it;
    it=dir.find(name);
    if(it!=dir.end()&& it->second>=1)
    dir[name]-=1;
    else dir[name]=0;
}
string small(string s1,string s2)
{
    int l=min(s1.size(),s2.size());
    if(s1==s2)return s1;
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)if(s1[i]>s2[i])return s2;
        return s1;
    }
}
int main() 
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int n,k;
    int tc,cs=0;
    cin >> tc;
    while(tc--){cout<<"Case "<<++cs<<":"<<endl;
    cin >> n >> k;
    string words;
    deque<ps>Q;
    deque<ps>::iterator it;
    Q.clear();
    dir.clear();
    int max =-1;
    string mf;
    while(n--)
    {
        cin>> words;
        if(Q.size()<k)
        {
            int c = lookup(words);
            Q.push_back(ps(words,c));
            it=Q.end()-1;
            if(it->second > max)
            {
                    max = it->second;
                    mf = it->first;
            }
            else if(max==it->second)
            {
                max = it->second;
                mf = small(mf,it->first);
            }
            cout <<mf<<" "<<max<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            map<string,int>::iterator itm;
            if(Q.size() >= k)
            {
                it=Q.begin();
                update(it->first);
                itm=dir.find(it->first);
                if(itm->second>0)
                max-=1;
                Q.pop_front();
                int c = lookup(words);
                Q.push_back(ps(words,c));
                it=Q.end()-1;
                itm=dir.find(mf);
                if(it->second > itm->second)
                {
                    max = it->second;
                    mf = it->first;
                }
                else if(it->second == itm->second)
                {
                    max = it->second;
                    mf = small(itm->first,it->first);
                }
                cout <<mf<<" "<<max<<endl;
            }

        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And test cases:

```
Sample test cases:
  1
  8 3
  hello
  hi
  who
  hi
  hi
  hello
  who
  when

correct output 
Case 1:
  hello 1
  hello 1
  hello 1
  hi 2
  hi 2
  hi 2
  hello 1
  hello 1

Mine code output
Case 1:
  hello 1
  hello 1
  hello 1
  hi 2
  hi 2
  hi 2
  who 1
  when 1
```

Comment: Basic idea: maintain a map of words to counts. Also maintain a k-sized array of words. When a new word is entered, check the size of the array. If the array is full, delete the oldest word, shift the elements down, add the new element; decrement the count of the (now deleted) oldest word from the map, increment the count of the new word in the map. Print the word in the map with the greatest value. Continue

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I have tried the same idea I am using the map to store the words and its frequencies when ever new word come. I am using deque to store the words and when it reaches to the limit k then I am deleting the old word and again maintaining the map by decreasing it frequency. Same thing I am doing but getting wrong answer. Here is the problem link [link]http://www.spoj.com/problems/WORDCNT2/

Comment: You don't need a deque - a queue with a max size will suffice. I can't help with implementation details, as I do not have the required expertise in C++

Comment: "It sometimes does not do what I want". "When the input is XYZ the output is ABC while I expect IJK". Which wording is likely to attract more answers? You decide.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard and is likely to discourage would-be contributors that use some other implementation. Prefer portable code.

Comment: BTW, your program returns correct result. It is just the tie which is not handled as expected (and it is not clear how to handle them: sort by lexicography order, or first item inserted ?).

Comment: @Jarod42 "In case there is a tie, print the alphabetically smaller word." (their words; not mine, so.. the former of your choices =).

Comment: Pass strings to functions by const reference. You could even return the string from `small` by const reference, as it only returns a parameter.

Comment: The problem statement doesn't specify what to do in case of a tie, so there's more than one correct output. Yours is as correct as theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following may help:

```
class Counter
{
public:
    Counter(std::size_t size) : max_size(size) {}

    void AddWord(const std::string& word)
    {
        if (words.size() == max_size) {
            auto it = counts.find(words.front());
            --it->second;
            if (it->second == 0) {
                counts.erase(it);
            }
            words.pop();
        }
        words.push(word);
        ++counts[word];
    }

    const std::pair<const std::string, std::size_t>& getMax() const
    {
        return *std::max_element(counts.begin(), counts.end(),
        [](const std::pair<const std::string, std::size_t>& lhs, const std::pair<const std::string, std::size_t>& rhs)
        {
            return std::tie(lhs.second, rhs.first) < std::tie(rhs.second, lhs.first);
        });
    }

private:
    std::size_t max_size;
    std::queue<std::string> words;
    std::map<std::string, std::size_t> counts;
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0391980a8316c175)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Jarod42's solution to be used with g++4.3.2 but the approach with
the max_element function is too slow. A faster algorithm is needed.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int max_size;
string words[100000];
map<string, size_t> counts;
int ifrontword,ilastword;

bool mycmp( pair<const string, size_t>& lhs,  pair<const string, size_t>& rhs){
  if (lhs.second==rhs.second) return rhs.first<lhs.first;
  else return lhs.second<rhs.second;
}
map<string, size_t>::iterator it;

void AddWord(string& word){    
  if (ilastword-ifrontword == max_size) {
    counts[words[ifrontword]]--;
    if (counts[words[ifrontword]]==0)
      counts.erase(words[ifrontword]);
    ifrontword++;
  }
  words[ilastword++]=word;
  counts[word]++;
}

pair<const string, size_t>& getMax() {
  return *max_element(counts.begin(), counts.end(), mycmp);
}

int main(){
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  int n,k;
  int tc,cs=0;
  string word;
  scanf("%d",&tc);
  while(tc--){
    cout<<"Case "<<++cs<<":"<<endl;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
    max_size=k;
    counts.clear();
    ilastword=ifrontword=0;
    while(n--){
      cin>> word;
      AddWord(word);
      pair<const string, size_t> &p = getMax();
      cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```